# Could not find transform-api.jar (com.android.tools.build:transform-api:2.0.0-deprecated-use-gradle-api)

Tags: android, android-studio

I get this error When I run my app in android studio 3.2.1:

```
Could not find transform-api.jar 
(com.android.tools.build:transform-api:2.0.0-deprecated-use-gradle-api).
```

Questions:

1. What is the transform-api.jar?
2. How do I use the transform-api.jar in my app?
3. Should i update my android studio? I updated all of the sdk.

All messages in the build:

```
Could not find transform-api.jar (com.android.tools.build:transform-api:2.0.0-deprecated-use-gradle-api).
Searched in the following locations:
    https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/transform-api/2.0.0-deprecated-use-gradle-api/transform-api-2.0.0-deprecated-use-gradle-api.jar
```

Comment: is there anybody to answere me?

Comment: finally i found a way. i live in iran and we cannot download directly android library. i changed gradle number in         classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
and i tried to update it.

Answer (score 9):

in my case, i solved with add **google maven** to build.gradle like this:

```
repositories {
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        mavenCentral()
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
```

and after that, if you receive **"lifecycle runtime"** error add this dependencies :

```
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'
```

Comment: This works! Just make sure to put google() AFTER mavenCentral(). I had forgotten to do that and after rearranging them it worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I solved this with a trick.
open **settings.gradle** and disable ->
`include ':app'` 
Then select from **File -> Sync Project With Gradle File** 
and re-enable the line -> `include ':app'` 
I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I just updated the gradle and the plugin version to the latest version via File > Project Structure > Project and the problem was fixed